# Change a dot '.' to a comma ',' and add a zero '0' to a price in react native

Tags: react-native

I want to change a string in the format of 2.8 to 2,80 in react native

```
class HomeComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

state= {

price : '2.8', // I get it in this format from Mysql
}

render() {
    return (
<View>
<TouchableOpacity>
<Text> Price : {this.state.price}</Text>
</TouchableOpacity></View>)}
}

export default HomeComponent;
```

I thought about using split like this

```
{this.state.price !== undefined ? this.state.price.split('.') : ''}
```

But it didn't work

Comment: Are you trying to localize the price?

Comment: localize, what does it mean ?

Comment: I'm trying to change the format from 2.8 that i get from a float in mysql to 2,80

Comment: Localize as in change the format of the number to a different language

Comment: no no, i can get it as a string, a float or whatever,i just need to change the format. If i just find out how to get the first part, add a coma, and then the second part using split, that would do the work i think

Comment: I understand that, but it seems like you are doing this because `2.8` and `2,80` appear to be the same number represented in different languages.

Comment: Ok, so what can I do ?

Comment: I would reccomend using a library like `react-intl` to handle this conversion - https://formatjs.io/docs/react-intl/components#formattednumber.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call this function with the number/string you want to convert.

```js
price = (e) => {
    z = e.toString()
    zf = z.split(".")[0] 
    zs = z.split(".")[1]
    if (!zs) zs = "00" 
    if (zs.length == 1) {
        return [zf,zs].join(",") + "0"
    } else {
        return [zf,zs].join(",")
    }
}
```

Use it as such:

```js
price(2.7) // 2,70
price(100) // 100,00
console.log(price(16.52)) // logs "16,52" to the console
```

Or in a Vue project:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    banana: 12.7
  },
  methods: {
    price(e) {
      z = e.toString() // to string, in case it's a number
      zf = z.split(".")[0]
      zs = z.split(".")[1]
      if (!zs) zs = "00" // add two zeroes if there's no decimal point
      if (zs.length == 1) {
        return [zf, zs].join(",") + "0" // add a zero if there's one number
      } else {
        return [zf, zs].join(",") // return if both are present
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>
    {{price(banana)}} <!-- banana is an example, you should replace it with the data from your DB -->
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Beautiful solution, how do I call the function inside the text tag <Text> price ({this.state.price})</Text> ?

Comment: `<Text> price ({price(this.state.price)})</Text>`

Comment: you can put the function in the methods section like i did [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tgzuwk73/)

Comment: nice one . . . .